# How to repeatedly add values in data frame rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, recurrence

I illustrate my question with a small date frame such as:

```
   X1 X2 X3
1   0  1  2
2   0  1  3
3   0  1  4
4   0  2  3
5   0  2  4
6   0  3  4
7   1  2  3
8   1  2  4
9   1  3  4
10  2  3  4
```

(The real one will have a huge number of rows...)
I have to expand **each row** of this data frame with **12 additional values**, considering that the 3 values already present are the 3 starting terms of a series defined by the recurrence equation:

```
U(n) = U(n-1) - Min(U(n-2), U(n-3))
```

Consider for example the 1st row with 0, 1, 2. The next term (4th) has to be :

```
2 - Min(1, 0) = 2 - 0 = 2
```

etc.  At the end, my first row will be :

```
0 1 2 2 1 -1 -2 -1 1 3 4 3 0 -3 -3
```

And I have to repeat this operation on each row of my initial data frame. Of course, I know I can use intricated loops "for {***}" to do this, but it's time consuming.

Is there any way to build the final data frame column by column? (I mean not listing the rows but constructing at once entire columns based on the recurrence equation)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write an 'intricate loop' and work row by row. You can write just one simple loop and calculate column by column such as:

```
# recreate the sample dataframe
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep(0, 6), 1,1,1,2),
                   X2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,4,2,2,3,3),
                   X3 = c(2,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,4,4))

# create placeholder dataframe full of zeros
temp <- data.frame(matrix(data = 0, nrow = 10, ncol = 15))

# write the original dataframe into the placeholder dataframe
temp[, 1:3] <- data

# for columns 4 to 15 in the placeholder dataframe
for(i in 4:15)
{
        # calculate each column based on the given formula
        temp[, i] <- temp[, i-1] - pmin(temp[,i-2], temp[, i-3])
}
```

Comment: Well, there is a problem with "min(temp[,i-2], temp[, i-3])". It calculates the min of **all values** of the 2 columns temp[,i-2] and temp[, i-3]... which is not right. The "min" is to be calculated on values of a row.

Comment: @Andrew Just change `min` to `pmin` and it should work

Comment: Haha, it wasnt your mistake, I had there a typo :)

Comment: By the way, after constructing "data", the instruction data[, 4] <- pmin(data[,1], data[, 2], data[, 3]) works well, but instruction data[, 4] <- pmin(data[, 1:3]) fails... No way to avoid this ? I didn't find anything clear in pmin documentation.